# Added heroku-repo to tower, how do I add the branches?

Tags: git, heroku, git-tower

I use git tower for managing my repos and heroku for hosting. Usually I create repos locally and the push them to heroku. In this case I want to clone down an existing heroku.

"Cloned the remote repository"-button using the git-repo-url. I can se the project in tower and a git-repo is created in the local folder. However, none of the remote repos are visible. Do I need to add them or something?

Answer (score 0):

Did you expand the "origin" item in Tower's sidebar, under the "REMOTES" section? In case you need more help, please just send an email to support@git-tower.com with a little bit more info (including screenshots etc.).